# Quotes are ignored in search when there's a word/tag outside quotes

Tags: bug, search, quotation-marks

I noticed that a search for [`multiple "pattern people watch however go the pattern"`](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=multiple+%22pattern+people+watch+however+go+the+pattern%22) (for example) returns 1 result (which is nonsense — it should be 0) but [removing the first word](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22pattern+people+watch+however+go+the+pattern%22) returns 0 results (as expected). [Moving the unquoted word to the end](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20%22pattern%20people%20watch%20however%20go%20the%20pattern%22%20multiple) also returns 0 results.

Another example: [`please "fix it fix it fix it fix the search"`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=please+%22fix+it+fix+it+fix+it+fix+the+search%22): 90 results. [Without first word](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22fix%20it%20fix%20it%20fix%20it%20fix%20the%20search%22): 0 results.

A key part here is that the searches above should not return any results. Searches which do match posts don't display a bug like this.

The current behavior isn't helpful. I'm not told that what I typed in doesn't have any results ([but maybe it used to?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5CT4.png)) and it's incredibly confusing to see so many results and check them and not find what the search was supposed to find (the exact quoted text).

---

From a [previous bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279945/323179) I had these tag searches:

- [Coffee:](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bcaffeine%5D+%22dark+light%22) `[caffeine] "dark light"` and [without tag](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20%22dark%20light%22)
- [Science Fiction and Fantasy:](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bmovie%5D+%22potter+and+harry%22) `[movie] "potter and harry"` and [without tag](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%20%22potter%20and%20harry%22). (Note that none of the posts that show up in the second search should turn up in the tag search)
- [スタック・オーバーフロー (Japanese SO):](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+%22controller+default%22) `[php] "controller default"` and [without tag](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%20%22controller%20default%22)

The behavior I initially reported there (added quotes) was fixed according to Yaakov:

> Part of the internal workings of search is that in some cases where the initial terms return zero results, it will perform a variant search using the same terms (but surrounded by quotes). This variant search ended up leaking back into the UI in a confusing way. No longer an issue.

But the tag searches still returned results when they shouldn't. When I asked about why they returned results:

> The results shown when searching for [the Coffee SE search] are the result of the variant search that I referred to. Must have missed the title, will get to that soon, thanks.

Still, I think it should be fixed.

Comment: @HenryEcker It looks like it already does. See [search help (Japanese)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) — it's the second bullet.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the link. It seems that doesn't work as expected and there's [already a report](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3113/51885) ([or two](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3114/51885)). Sorry for the side track.