# Exact phrase search with tag gets wrapped with additional set of quotes on Meta.SE

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, meta

Only on **Meta Stack Exchange**, searching with an exact phrase in the search box will result in the entire query wrapped in an additional pair of quotes.

For example:

`[feature-request] "There are no review queues available to you"`

searches for:

`"[feature-request] "There are no review queues available to you""`

This doesn't seem to be an issue on Stack Overflow & Meta.SO, as well as [network-wide search](https://stackexchange.com/search).

---

I'm seeing this on:

- Windows 10, Chrome 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10, Firefox 64.0.2 (64-bit)

---

This issue is very similar to [Search is adding quotes to searches starting or ending with very specific quoted phrases](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/275815/165483) reported and [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in 2016.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Quotes break the search](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/279945/quotes-break-the-search)

Comment: @Laurel no, yours should be closed as a duplicate of the one I linked above, as it was previously fixed. This is a new issue which does not affect all sites.

Comment: I get the same thing happening on SO and other sites with the right query. The link is still in my post that causes it. Also your proposed duplicate was originally referenced in my question. My question there was not marked as status completed because all the bugs were not fixed the last time I checked (which was after the other one was marked status completed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is now fixed.

Part of the internal workings of search is that in some cases where the initial terms return zero results, it will perform a variant search using the same terms (but surrounded by quotes). This variant search ended up leaking back into the UI in a confusing way. No longer an issue.